# Trouble with logic in very easy if-statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

So I cant figure out the logic behind this very simple if-statement

```
int found = 0, value = 5;
if (!found || ‐‐value == 0)
cout << "danger ";
cout << "value = " << value << endl;
```

Why does "danger" being written to the screen here? I thought since found = 0, !found is not euqual to zero.

Comment: Because `!found` is not equal to `0` (or `false`, I'd say).

Comment: The answer is in your question: "since found = 0, !found is not equal to zero", thus the test condition must be true.

Comment: is it maybe the short-cuircit that confuses you? You would get the same with `if (!found) { cout << "danger"; }` because if the first operand is true, the second isnt even evaluated

Comment: Replace        `||` with `&&` and it will print **value** instead of **danger**

Comment: you should declare `found` as bool otherwise `!found` gives the inverted binary form of 0,that is, 1 which would always give true inside given `if` condition.

Comment: @ShubhamSinghManhas True in `C`, not in `C++`. See the standardese in my answer.

Comment: @BoBTFish good point there...

Comment: @Subham The rules for implicit conversion of integer to bool are the same for C and C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are considering the condition in the if statement the following way

```
if ( ( !found == 0 ) || ( ‐‐value == 0 ) )
```

However in C++ the condition in the if statement is equivalent to

```
if ( ( !found ) || ( ‐‐value == 0 ) )
```

that in turn is equivalent to

```
if ( ( found == 0 ) || ( ‐‐value == 0 ) )
```

So as the found is indeed equal to 0 then this subexpression `( found == 0 )` yields true and it is the result of the logical OR operator.

Comment: Get out of my mind Vlad! Excactly my thought process, thank you very much. Really appreciate it .

Answer (score 1):

When converting integers booleans, `0` is `false` and anything else is `true`:

1. `found == 0` - `found` is `0`
2. `(bool)found == false` - `0` is interpreted as `false`
3. `!found == true` - `not false` is `true`
4. `(!found || anything else) == true` - if the first half of an `or` is `true`, the whole expression is `true`.
5. `if (!found || anything else) { // always hit! }`

Note that the boolean expressions `||` and `&&` have *short-circuiting*. So if the value of the entire expression is determined my the first sub-expression, the second sub-expression isn't even evaluation:

- `true || who cares`
- `false && who cares`

---

Language-lawyering:

> 5.3.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op]
>
> ...
>
> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator `!` is contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4); its value is `true` if the converted operand is `false` and `false` otherwise. The type of the result is `bool`.

Comment: Very immediate downvote?! I thought I made the logical leap quite clear, care to explain what's wrong or confusing?

Comment: didnt downvote, though I think first `operator!` is applied to the `int` and only when `||` is applied the operand is converted to bool

Comment: @tobi303 Hm, I think you are right, strictly speaking the result is of `int` type. I hoped to make this easy to understand for a beginner though. I'll try to rewrite that.

Comment: So is the if-statement a bool? So we say only run when the statement is false?

Comment: Why not simply state ( !found ) <=> ! ( found != 0 ) <=> ( found == 0 ) ?

Comment: @SuchARush Be it **if(condition)** or **while(condition)** (any conditional statement) they work only when the **condition** is `TRUE`.

Comment: It would be also be important to point out that value is not decremented in this case.

Comment: I get it now, thank you BobTFish/and rest of you guys), really appreciate it!!

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Is that because its in a statement?

Comment: @SuchARush It's because of short-circuiting, which means that in conditional statements, where result of an entire expression is already known (e.g. `true || anything` is always `true`), the rest of expression (`anything` in previous example) is not executed.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Ah, of course. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the test  statement into a logic that's closer to what the compiler does:

```
if (!found || --value == 0)
{
   cout << "danger";
}
```

Is understood logically by the compiler as something closer to this (expanded a bit for the example, since the assembly actually generated uses reverse logic...).

```
if (found == 0)   // !found
{
    cout << "danger";    // if this is executed, the next test is not !
}
else if (--value == 0)
{
    cout << "danger";
}
```

The compiler uses reverse logic, so it does not have to generate the `cout << "danger"` statement twice.

as in:

```
if (found == 0)
{
    goto print_danger;
}
else 
{
   -- value;        // this statement is never executed if (found == 0)
   if (value != 0)
   {
      goto skip_print_danger;
   }
}

print_danger:
  cout << "danger";

skip_print_danger:
 cout << "value = " << value;
```

Comment: Good side notes. Thanks :)